# Consume RabbitMq using Pika and push using Socket.io

Tags: python, socket.io, rabbitmq, celery, pika

I am building a service that receives messages from `rabbitmq` using `pika`. and push messages to clients using `socket.io`.

The `socket.io` server and pika server are both blocking the main thread.
This will be the same also for `celery` with `flask` or `Django`.

What is the proper approach to solving this and run them both under the same context?

Comment: Setting up 2 scripts that run individually from each other is no option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Pub/Sub` model, Start the consume process in another thread register user that want to receive from the queue and send data to subscribed users.

```py
import json
import pika
import gevent
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

connection_url = 'localhost'
channel_queue = 'test'

class PubSubListener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue_name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.clients = []
        self.queue_name = queue_name

        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(connection_url))
        self.channel = connection.channel()
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name)

        threading.Thread(target=self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue_name,
            auto_ack=True,
            on_message_callback=self._callback))

    def run(self):
        self.channel.start_consuming()

    def publish(self, body):
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
            routing_key=self.queue_name,
            body=body)

    def subscribe(self, client):
        self.clients.append(client)

    def _callback(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        message = json.loads(body)
        print(message)
        self.send(message)

    def send(self, data):
        for client in self.clients:
            try:
                client.send(data)
            except Exception:
                self.clients.remove(client)

pslistener = PubSubListener(channel_queue)

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    pslistener.subscribe(ws)

    while not ws.closed:
        gevent.sleep(0.1)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    pslistener.start()

    print("Started")
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```